# Perl - how to create function that accepts various data types

Tags: perl, function, inheritance, polymorphism, subroutine

In some perl functions I want be able to work with various types of arguments and of course treat them differently. Now I am using for this `ref` function and execute appropriate part of code based on `ref` result, e.g.

```
sub method_that_accept_various_data_types(){
  if (ref $_[0] eq "ARRAY"){
    # ...
  }
  elsif (ref $_[0] eq "SCALAR"){
    # ...
  }
  elsif (ref $_[0] eq "HASH"){
    # ...
  }
}
```

Is there some elegant way by which I can say that all my functions should follow this pattern  or I have to use mentioned code at the beginning of all my subroutines? I am writing procedural code and I thing something similar is polymorphism and inheritance in OOP but I am newbie in this area.

**Edit**
All answers needs to append the code to all newly created function. I am asking if there is some generic way of doing this for every function defined from now without the need for adding code to new function.

Comment: You shouldn't make such functions as they are inherently buggy

Comment: Why? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Because something can be both a hash and an array (etc). If you don't want to provide multiple functions, base your polymorphism on the number of arguments or on the name of arguments (when using `foo => $foo` arguments).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use hash of functions/dispatch table, but it is basically the same approach,

```
sub method_that_accept_various_data_types {

  my $ref = ref($_[0]);

  my $func = {
    ARRAY => sub {
      print "$ref\n";
    },
    SCALAR => sub {
      print "$ref\n";
    },
    HASH => sub {
      print "$ref\n";
    },
  }->{$ref} or return;

  $func->(@_);
}
```

Comment: Be sure to pass `@_` to the anonymous sub because it won't be able to access the outer `@_` anymore.

Comment: @DanielBöhmer tnx for comment.

Comment: With your recent edit you're removing the 1st element of interest from `@_` and *do not* pass it to the sub! Stick to `$_[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `switch` statement from the [`Switch` module](https://metacpan.org/pod/Switch)

```
use Switch;

sub polymorph_function {
    my ($arg1, $arg2, ...) = @_;

    switch (ref $arg1) {
        case 'ARRAY' { ... }
        case 'HASH'  { ... }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Switch shouldn't be recommended. It's a source filter, it can cause strange bugs.

Comment: As an alternative if you know your code will only run on Perl 5.10.1 or higher, you can use [the `switch` feature](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Switch-Statements). That's almost the same but with different keywords: `for` or `given` and `when`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this based on Сухой27's example as an additional answer because I'd personally consider it bad code. But if you prefer short code you might like it:

```
sub polymorph_function {
    ({
        ARRAY => sub { ... },
        HASH  => sub { ... },
        ...
    }->{ref $_[0]} || return)->(@_);
}
```

It's basically the same, except that there are no temporary variables. It creates an anonymous hash and its reference is directly dereferenced and the appropriate key selected based on `ref $_[0]` (type of the 1st argument). The resulting coderef to one of the subs is then called immediately with all arguments to the original sub.

Answer (score -1):

I just thought about ways to move much of the code to a central place.

```
sub polymorph_function {
    poly \@_, (
        ARRAY => sub { ... },
        HASH  => sub { ... },
        ...
    );
}

sub poly {
    my ($args, %subs) = @_;

    my $sub = $subs{ref $args->[0]} or return;
    $sub->( @$args );
}
```